# HTML not properly decoded from the database in ASP.NET MVC View

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper, html-encode

I used the TinyMCE editor to post content to the database so I've got html codes in the database. When I tried outputting it on my MVC View, the details page displayed perfectly with all the html formatting but the readmore page is outputting some html raw characters. Below is the code for the details view which outputs my html properly:

```
<h3>
    @Html.Raw(Model.articleContent)
</h3>
```

And below is the code for the entire page where I have the read more.

```
<h3>
    @{
        var articleContent = @Html.Raw(item.articleContent);
        ViewBag.articleContent = articleContent.ToString().Substring(0,300);
    }

    @ViewBag.articleContent
</h3>
```

The output I get for the above is like the below content:

Some test article title

```html
<p>Team Aquamarine &ndash; Ola Ehimigbai, Murtala Saleh<br />PT,CSS ,SD Office, GRC,HRT and SP, this is quite a merger and Roland Guobadia, Lukman Longe and Cajetan and Igbokwe would hope that theirs, is a team that would finish up in the medal table, the light blue color of team aquamarine is the f
```

Comment: Can you point out precisely which line is outputting the incorrect text?  I can't work it out cause you have 3 versions of `articleContent`... `item.articleContent`, `ViewBag.articleContent` and `Model.articleContent` and the code shows a `<h3>` and the output a `<p>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Html.Raw` with `ViewBag.articleContent` because you want to display html which is in ViewBag.articleContent.

```
     ...
     @{
          ViewBag.articleContent = item.articleContent.Substring(0,300);
     }
     @Html.Raw(ViewBag.articleContent)
</h3>
...
```

Or you can even make it simpler:

```
...
<h3>@Html.Raw(item.articleContent.Substring(0,300))</h3>
...
```

Comment: But `ViewBag.articleContent` already is the output of `Html.Raw()`

Comment: @Coulton Yes you are right but later there is `ViewBag.articleContent = articleContent.ToString()` and that make `ViewBag.articleContent` to be regular string.

Comment: What is the point in running `Html.Raw()` on it before then and surely `articleContent` is already a string so no need for `ToString()`?

Comment: I'd say it's better practice to set the ViewBag in the controller... even better practice would be to not use the view bag at all. You've got the variable in the view model... why use the viewbag?

Comment: @Coulton there is no need to run `Html.Raw` before but if you do this it return `IHtmlString` and then you need to use `ToString`.

@Heberda Sure it is bad practice but here we see only part of code maybe there is some reason for this....